# Two wrapfigure overlapping; delay starting point of wrapfigure associated text

Tags: wrapfigure

Working on my thesis and I want to have two wrapfigures (left and right) fit in one page. To be able to do this, one has to go inside the text area of the other. How can I delay locally the start of the associated text of the second wrapfigure?

[image]

Code here:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[12]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{-10pt}
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{p2_vs_cable_length.png}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}
\caption{Top: Extra capacitance (cable length) between GEM bottom and $R_dec$ (induction gap; one GEM setup). Bottom: capacitance between $R_{\mathrm{dec}}$ and the PS \cite{cable_capacitance_effect}.}
\label{fig:p2_vs_cable_length}
\end{wrapfigure}


Previous works have shown that extra capacitance pushes the occurrence of secondary discharges at lower fields. A longer cable will introduce more capacitance in the system. This has to be properly decoupled from the sensible GEM, by use of a $R_dec$ (the top side always features the $R_L$, with a very high ohmic value). \par 

If this extra capacitance is situated between the GEM bottom and $R_dec$ (Fig. \ref{fig:p2_vs_cable_length}, top), the effect is the onset of secondaries shifts toward lower values, as the capacitance increases. \par 

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{-10pt}
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{p2_vs_cable_length_vs_r_dec.png}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}
\caption{A high enough ohmic path ensures that extra capacitance does not influence the secondary discharge probability \cite{cable_capacitance_effect}.}
\label{fig:p2_vs_cable_length_vs_r_dec}
\end{wrapfigure}


This is because at the time of a discharge, not only the capacitor formed by the two sides of the GEM discharges, but also the extra reservoir of capacitance given by the cables and other parasitic capacitances in the RC system. This motivated the need to install decoupling resistors close to the chambers. \par

If extra capacitance is located between the $R_dec$ and the PS, there appears to be no effect on the secondary onset, but this might change with the value of $R_dec$. \par 

If low $R_dec$ are used, the dependence on the cable length is visible. The \textit{decoupling power} increases with a bigger value $R_dec$, showing that higher resistance is preferred.
```

If necessary - A4 size page, first wrapfigure is 547x563, second one is 604x1024.

Played with \vspace{some value} after the second wrapfigure, but it shifts the whole figure down, not just the text. Can I decouple the text from the wrapfigure environment?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses paracol to effect two intermingled columns.  Note that paracol supports figures.  Also, it can produce uneven widths (if desired).

The `\hrule` was used to show where to split the last paragraph.  Consecutive `\strut`s produce a `\baselineskip` spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{paracol}

\globalcounter{figure}

%\newcommand{\nopar}{{\parfillskip=0pt\par}}% for manual paragraph splitting

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
Previous works have shown that extra capacitance pushes the occurrence of secondary 
discharges at lower fields. A longer cable will introduce more capacitance in the system. 
This has to be properly decoupled from the sensible GEM, by use of a $R_dec$ 
(the top side always features the $R_L$, with a very high ohmic value). \par

If this extra capacitance is situated between the GEM bottom and $R_dec$ 
(Fig. \ref{fig:p2_vs_cable_length}, top), the effect is the onset of secondaries shifts 
toward lower values, as the capacitance increases. \par% BTW, this is redundant.  Blank lines are translated as \par

\switchcolumn

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{justification=centering}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=1.07\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  %\captionsetup{format=myformat}% no myformat defined
  \caption{Top: Extra capacitance (cable length) between GEM bottom and $R_dec$ 
    (induction gap; one GEM setup). Bottom: capacitance between $R_{\mathrm{dec}}$ and the 
    PS \cite{cable_capacitance_effect}.}
  \label{fig:p2_vs_cable_length}
\end{figure}

\switchcolumn

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{justification=centering}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=1.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  %\captionsetup{format=myformat}
  \caption{A high enough ohmic path ensures that extra capacitance does not influence 
    the secondary discharge probability \cite{cable_capacitance_effect}.}
  \label{fig:p2_vs_cable_length_vs_r_dec}
\end{figure}
\hrule% show bottom of column
\switchcolumn

This is because at the time of a discharge, not only the capacitor formed 
by the two sides of the GEM discharges, but also the extra reservoir of capacitance 
given by the cables and other parasitic capacitances in the RC system. 
This motivated the need to install decoupling resistors close to the chambers. \par

This is because at the time of a discharge, not only the capacitor formed by the two 
sides of the GEM discharges, but also the extra reservoir of capacitance given by the 
cables and other parasitic capacitances in the RC system. 
This motivated the need to install decoupling resistors close to the chambers. \par

If extra capacitance is located between the $R_dec$ and the PS, there appears to be no effect 
on the secondary onset, but this might change with the value of $R_dec$.
\hrule height0pt
\end{paracol}

\strut If low $R_dec$ are used, the dependence on the cable length is visible.
The \textit{decoupling power} increases with a bigger value $R_dec$, showing that higher resistance is preferred.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This is wonderful! Exactly what I needed. I knew wrapfigure had some trouble when overlaying with another. But it was not the case, right? 
Where does the wrapfig environment end? Is it also the accompanying text? I feel that messing with the text on the side of the wrapfig should not influence the figure itself. But they seem coupled. Is there any way to "decouple" the two?

Comment: You can cut short one wrapfig, but it then loses track of how much space was supposed to be reserved.

Answer (score 0):

As the figures fill the whole width of the column, you do not need any wrapfigure, and the redular figure does the job without any complicated code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
Previous works have shown that extra capacitance pushes the occurrence of secondary discharges at lower fields. 
A longer cable will introduce more capacitance in the system. This has to be properly decoupled from the sensible GEM, 
by use of a $R_dec$ (the top side always features the $R_L$, with a very high ohmic value).

If this extra capacitance is situated between the GEM bottom and $R_dec$ (Fig. \ref{fig:p2_vs_cable_length}, top), the effect is the onset of secondaries shifts toward lower values, as the capacitance increases. 

\begin{figure}[thbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=9cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{A high enough ohmic path ensures that extra capacitance does not influence  the secondary discharge probability}
\label{fig:p2_vs_cable_length_vs_r_dec}
\end{figure}


This is because at the time of a discharge, not only the capacitor formed 
by the two sides of the GEM discharges, but also the extra reservoir of capacitance 
given by the cables and other parasitic capacitances in the RC system. 
This motivated the need to install decoupling resistors close to the chambers. 

This is because at the time of a discharge, not only the capacitor formed by the two 
sides of the GEM discharges, but also the extra reservoir of capacitance given by the 
cables and other parasitic capacitances in the RC system. 
This motivated the need to install decoupling resistors close to the chambers. 

If extra capacitance is located between the $R_dec$ and the PS, there appears to be no effect 
on the secondary onset, but this might change with the value of $R_dec$.

\begin{figure}[thbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=12cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Top: Extra capacitance (cable length) between GEM bottom and $R_dec$ (induction gap; one GEM setup). Bottom: capacitance between $R_{\mathrm{dec}}$ and the PS \cite{cable_capacitance_effect}.}
\label{fig:p2_vs_cable_length}
\end{figure}

If low $R_dec$ are used, the dependence on the cable length is visible.
The \textit{decoupling power} increases with a bigger value $R_dec$, showing that higher resistance is preferred.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution :) Unfortunately, the thesis is not structured as a two column article, so I use the whole width. Forgot to mention it.

Comment: Ok, i made  a mistake when looking at your screenshot. In such case I also ressort to mini pages and some time raisebox.

Comment: And in such case, why not combine the two figures in a single (floating) one using `subfigure` env from `subcaption` package ?