# Wrapfigure two figures left and right with text in between

Tags: wrapfigure

I wish to accomplish something like:

[image]

Where **1** and **2** are images. **1** is aligned to the left and **2** is aligned to the right. All text between those should be as illustrated with lines in the image.

My current code is:

```
\clearpage
\newpage

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image1.png}
\caption{Image 1}
\end{wrapfigure}

Really long text to be on the right of image 1...

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.40\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image2.png}
\caption{Image 2}
\end{wrapfigure}

Really long text to be on the left of image 2...
```

However, my code results in **Image 1** being on the left (as it should be) with the text which belongs to it on its right (as it should be) and the text which should be on the left of **Image 2** immediately after the text of **Image 1** (why?). And **Image 2** is on a new page and still on the left. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are you open to use other packages or tricks to achieve what you want? Or you want to stick to `wrapfigure` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this serve the purpose?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol,caption}
\newenvironment{Figure}
{\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
{\endminipage\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{Figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (1,1) circle (3cm);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof{figure}{text}
        \end{Figure}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{multicols}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[2]
        \begin{Figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (1,1) circle (3cm);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof{figure}{text}
        \end{Figure}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

I have not used `wrapfigure` here, but `multicols` can also serve something similar. I agree that this is not a good solution for you if you want to continue using `wrapfigure` environment.

Comment: Thank you. This worked out great.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, using the `insbox` plain TeX macro package: it defines `\InsertBoxL` and `InsertBoxR` commands with two mandatory arguments: the number of lines unshortened in the following paragraph, before the insertion of the box, and the content of the box, and a last  optional argument, the number of supplementary shortened lines, in case TeX has erroneously calculated  the height of the inserted box. Of course, the inserted objects are no more floating, so you have to use `\captionof{figure}{some caption}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption} 
\input{insbox}
\makeatletter
\@InsertBoxMargin=3mm
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxL{0}{%
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth ]{AliceSteadman}
\captionof{figure}{Ralph Steadman’s cover for Alice in Wonderland}
}}[10]
\lipsum[1]

{\InsertBoxR{6}{%
\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth ]{traccia-table}
\captionof{figure}{Meret Oppenheim Table with bird legs (1972)}
}}[7]
\lipsum[1-2]}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with wrapfig, so long as you make sure the first wrapfig is done before starting another.  `\wrapfill` adds blank lines (actually, paragraphs) until this point is reached.

Note, always use `\parskip=0pt` with wrapfig.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\wrapfill}{\par\ifnum\value{WF@wrappedlines}>0
  \addtocounter{WF@wrappedlines}{-1}%
  \null\vspace{\arabic{WF@wrappedlines}\baselineskip}%
  \WFclear
\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image 1}
\end{wrapfigure}

Really long text to be on the right of image 1...
\arabic{WF@wrappedlines}
\wrapfill

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.40\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Image 2}
\end{wrapfigure}

Really long text to be on the left of image 2...
\wrapfill

At this point the bottom wrapfigure is done.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, and fixed an issue I had with text still being wrapped on the next page despite the wrapfig ending sooner. I wonder why this isn't a standard feature of the package? The documentation doesn't really go over this.

Comment: BTW, I now recommend using paracol instead of wrapfig (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509450/two-wrapfigure-overlapping-delay-starting-point-of-wrapfigure-associated-text/509522?r=SearchResults&s=2|41.3936#509522)