# Collision between wrapping environments

Tags: wrapfigure

new to Latex. Today i'm having struggles with wrapfigure errors. In the image below there is the result of what I typed:

[image]

and this is what I want:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}




\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Foto grafici/} }
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
Si vanno ad esaminare quindi come variano l'utilità ed i prezzi relativi:
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Effetto di reddito è legato alla riduzione di utilità, si esamina mantenendo fissi i prezzi relativi.
        \item Effetto di sostituzione è legato alla variazione dei prezzi relativi, si calcola mantenendo costante l'utilità.
    \end{itemize}
    \subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene normale e ordinario con $p' > p$}
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}[13]{r}{0\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:1.png}
        \ht0=100pt % change this to move it up or down
        \dp0=0pt
        \box0
    \end{wrapfigure}
    
    
    Nella configurazione di prezzi iniziale $\frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ si ha il livello di scelta ottima pari a $x^A$. Successivamente avviene un aumento di prezzi che porta il vincolo di bilancio ad una pendenza $\frac{p'_{1}}{p_{2}} < \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ che riduce l'utilità perchè $x^{A}>x^{B} $. \newline Successivamente per analizzare i due effetti individualmente si dovrà andare a calcolare una combinazione ottima con gli stessi prezzi iniziali ma con l'utilità finale. Il vincolo di bilancio in esame è quello rosso con il relativo ottimo $x^{C}$. Il passaggio da $x^{A}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto di reddito, chiamato \textit{IE} mentre il passaggio da $x^{B}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto sostituzione chiamato \textit{SE}. 
    
    
    \subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene inferiore e ordinario con $p' > p$, \textit{SE = IE}}
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
      \centering
      \setbox0\hbox
        {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:2.png}}%
      \ht0=170pt % change this to move it up or down
      \box0
    \end{wrapfigure}
    
    In questo caso come vedi all'aumentare dei prezzi la quantità domandata non varia. Si sposta quindi il vincolo di bilancio dei prezzi iniziali finchè non è tangente alla curva di indifferenza finale. Si nota quindi che effetto reddito e sostituzione si compensano. L'effetto reddito va da $x^A$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo, mentre l'effetto sostituzione va da $x^B$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo. 
    
    \subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene inferiore e di Giffen con $p' > p$, \textit{SE = IE}}
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
      \centering
      \setbox0\hbox
        {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:3.png}}%
      \ht0=170pt % change this to move it up or down
      \box0
    \end{wrapfigure}
    
    La quantità domandata a seguito di un aumento di prezzo è più grande di quella iniziale, come puoi vedere $x^{A}>x^{B}$. Questo accade perchè l'effetto reddito è molto forte, mentre l'effetto sostituzione è decisamente più debole e quindi il consumatore sceglierà di acquistare di più.
\end{document}
```

Sorry if this might be too long. Hope someone can point me out where I'm doing wrong. Thank's.

Comment: In this specific case, I'd recommend using side-by-side minipages insetad of `wrapfig`.

Comment: Please make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: I've added requested fields. Also I don't know what minipage is.

Comment: Something like `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    your text here
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{Foto grafici/l-11:3.png}
\end{minipage}` should work fine in this case. Are there any subsubsections with longer texts, e.g. text that takes up more lines than the accompagnying image or are all texts equally long/shorter?

Comment: It gives me the following error: "package keyval error valign undefined".

Comment: All text are, more or less, equally longer. See images for reference.

Comment: Add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to your preamble. Sorry, I forgot to mention that in my previous comment.

Comment: That does not work. I get half page text followed by image.

Comment: I just added an answer to show how you could use the minipage-based approach. I hope the output of this MWE suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your texts are all rather short and you actually don't need the wrapping feature of `wrapfig` but instead just need some text and an image side-by-side, the following `minipage`-based appraoch should work. In order to prevent undefull box warnings, I also added the `babel` package (I hope I guessed the language correctly)  in order to load appropriate hyphenation patterns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the demo option in your actual document.
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document}

Si vanno ad esaminare quindi come variano l'utilità ed i prezzi relativi:

\begin{itemize}
    \item Effetto di reddito è legato alla riduzione di utilità, si esamina mantenendo fissi i prezzi relativi.
    \item Effetto di sostituzione è legato alla variazione dei prezzi relativi, si calcola mantenendo costante l'utilità.
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene normale e ordinario con $p' > p$}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    Nella configurazione di prezzi iniziale $\frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ si ha il livello di scelta ottima pari a $x^A$. Successivamente avviene un aumento di prezzi che porta il vincolo di bilancio ad una pendenza $\frac{p'_{1}}{p_{2}} < \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ che riduce l'utilità perchè $x^{A}>x^{B} $. \newline Successivamente per analizzare i due effetti individualmente si dovrà andare a calcolare una combinazione ottima con gli stessi prezzi iniziali ma con l'utilità finale. Il vincolo di bilancio in esame è quello rosso con il relativo ottimo $x^{C}$. Il passaggio da $x^{A}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto di reddito, chiamato \textit{IE} mentre il passaggio da $x^{B}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto sostituzione chiamato \textit{SE}. 

\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, valign=t]{Foto grafici/l-11:1.png}
\end{minipage}

\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene inferiore e ordinario con $p' > p$, \textit{SE = IE}}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    In questo caso come vedi all'aumentare dei prezzi la quantità domandata non varia. Si sposta quindi il vincolo di bilancio dei prezzi iniziali finchè non è tangente alla curva di indifferenza finale. Si nota quindi che effetto reddito e sostituzione si compensano. L'effetto reddito va da $x^A$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo, mentre l'effetto sostituzione va da $x^B$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo.
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, valign=t]{Foto grafici/l-11:2.png}
\end{minipage}


\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene inferiore e di Giffen con $p' > p$, \textit{SE = IE}}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    La quantità domandata a seguito di un aumento di prezzo è più grande di quella iniziale, come puoi vedere $x^{A}>x^{B}$. Questo accade perchè l'effetto reddito è molto forte, mentre l'effetto sostituzione è decisamente più debole e quindi il consumatore sceglierà di acquistare di più.
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{Foto grafici/l-11:3.png}
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I pasted this and the first time it worked, then I don't know why the third section moved to another page.

Comment: There is not enough space on the page to also include the third subsebsection. To make it fit onto the first page, as well, you could adjust teh widths of the `minipage` environments, e.g. `0.4\textwidth` for the image containing minipages and `0.55\textwidth` for the text containing ones.

Comment: Edit: i just needed to make images a little smaller by typing 0.90 in widht fields of images. Thank's again :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I managed to resolve my issue like this, I don't fully understand what I've done and I get several underfull \hbox error tough.

```
Si vanno ad esaminare quindi come variano l'utilità ed i prezzi relativi:

\begin{itemize}
    \item Effetto di reddito è legato alla riduzione di utilità, si esamina mantenendo fissi i prezzi relativi.
    \item Effetto di sostituzione è legato alla variazione dei prezzi relativi, si calcola mantenendo costante l'utilità.
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene normale e ordinario con $p' > p$}

\begin{wrapfigure}[13]{r}{0pt}
    \centering
    \setbox0\hbox
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:1.png}}
    \ht0=140pt % change this to move it up or down
    \dp0=0pt
    \box0
\end{wrapfigure}


Nella configurazione di prezzi iniziale $\frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ si ha il livello di scelta ottima pari a $x^A$. Successivamente avviene un aumento di prezzi che porta il vincolo di bilancio ad una pendenza $\frac{p'_{1}}{p_{2}} < \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ che riduce l'utilità perchè $x^{A}>x^{B} $. \newline Successivamente per analizzare i due effetti individualmente si dovrà andare a calcolare una combinazione ottima con gli stessi prezzi iniziali ma con l'utilità finale. Il vincolo di bilancio in esame è quello rosso con il relativo ottimo $x^{C}$. Il passaggio da $x^{A}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto di reddito, chiamato \textit{IE} mentre il passaggio da $x^{B}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto sostituzione chiamato \textit{SE}. 


\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene inferiore e ordinario con $p' > p$, \textit{SE = IE}}

\begin{wrapfigure}[13]{r}{0pt}
  \centering
  \setbox0\hbox
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:2.png}}%
  \ht0=170pt % change this to move it up or down
  \dp0=0pt
  \box0
\end{wrapfigure}

In questo caso come vedi all'aumentare dei prezzi la quantità domandata non varia. Si sposta quindi il vincolo di bilancio dei prezzi iniziali finchè non è tangente alla curva di indifferenza finale. Si nota quindi che effetto reddito e sostituzione si compensano. L'effetto reddito va da $x^A$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo, mentre l'effetto sostituzione va da $x^B$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo. 
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene inferiore e di Giffen con $p' > p$, \textit{SE < IE}}

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{0pt}
  \centering
  \setbox0\hbox
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:3.png}}%
  \ht0=170pt % change this to move it up or down
  \dp0=0pt
  \box0
\end{wrapfigure}

La quantità domandata a seguito di un aumento di prezzo è più grande di quella iniziale, come puoi vedere $x^{A}>x^{B}$. Questo accade perchè l'effetto reddito è molto forte, mentre l'effetto sostituzione è decisamente più debole e quindi il consumatore sceglierà di acquistare di più.
```

Comment: Your solution does not work in general but is specific to the images you use, without which it cannot be tested.  While specifying the number of lines (on a case by case basis) helps, it will not add gaps when the text is too short.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526518/wrapfigure-two-figures-left-and-right-with-text-in-between/526594?r=SearchResults&s=1|21.1604#526594

Answer (score 0):

I have become fond of using paracol instead of wrapfigure. The main drawback is that you have to manually break paragraphs.  However, this is no more difficult than counting or guessing the number of lines of text to use.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Foto grafici/} }
\usepackage{grffile}

\usepackage{paracol}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\nopar}[1]{% #1 = rest of paragraph after split
  \unskip\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}%
  \global\setbox\textbox=\vbox{\hsize=\textwidth\noindent\strut #1\strut}}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}

\begin{document}
Si vanno ad esaminare quindi come variano l'utilità ed i prezzi relativi:
    
\begin{itemize}
    \item Effetto di reddito è legato alla riduzione di utilità, si esamina mantenendo fissi i prezzi relativi.
    \item Effetto di sostituzione è legato alla variazione dei prezzi relativi, si calcola mantenendo costante l'utilità.
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene normale e ordinario con $p' > p$}
    
\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:1.png}}% get width 
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}%
\begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy
    Si vanno ad esaminare quindi come variano l'utilità ed i prezzi relativi:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Effetto di reddito è legato alla riduzione di utilità, si esamina mantenendo fissi i prezzi relativi.
    \item Effetto di sostituzione è legato alla variazione dei prezzi relativi, si calcola mantenendo costante l'utilità.
    \end{itemize}
\switchcolumn
    \usebox\tempbox
\end{paracol}

\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene normale e ordinario con $p' > p$}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:1.png}}% get width
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}%
\begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy
    Nella configurazione di prezzi iniziale $\frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ si ha il livello di scelta ottima pari a $x^A$. Successivamente avviene un aumento di prezzi che porta il vincolo di bilancio ad una pendenza $\frac{p'_{1}}{p_{2}} < \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ che riduce l'utilità perchè $x^{A}>x^{B} $. \newline Successivamente per analizzare i due effetti individualmente si dovrà andare a calcolare una combinazione ottima con gli stessi prezzi iniziali ma con l'utilità finale. Il vincolo di bilancio in esame è quello rosso con il relativo ottimo $x^{C}$. Il passaggio da $x^{A}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto di reddito, chiamato
\nopar{\textit{IE} mentre il passaggio da $x^{B}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto sostituzione chiamato \textit{SE}.}
\switchcolumn
    \usebox\tempbox
\end{paracol}
\continuepar

Nella configurazione di prezzi iniziale $\frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ si ha il livello di scelta ottima pari a $x^A$. Successivamente avviene un aumento di prezzi che porta il vincolo di bilancio ad una pendenza $\frac{p'_{1}}{p_{2}} < \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$ che riduce l'utilità perchè $x^{A}>x^{B} $. \newline Successivamente per analizzare i due effetti individualmente si dovrà andare a calcolare una combinazione ottima con gli stessi prezzi iniziali ma con l'utilità finale. Il vincolo di bilancio in esame è quello rosso con il relativo ottimo $x^{C}$. Il passaggio da $x^{A}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto di reddito, chiamato \textit{IE} mentre il passaggio da $x^{B}$ a $x^{C}$ è l'effetto sostituzione chiamato \textit{SE}. 


\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene inferiore e ordinario con $p' > p$, \textit{SE = IE}}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:2.png}}% get width
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}%
\begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy
In questo caso come vedi all'aumentare dei prezzi la quantità domandata non varia. Si sposta quindi il vincolo di bilancio dei prezzi iniziali finchè non è tangente alla curva di indifferenza finale. Si nota quindi che effetto reddito e sostituzione si compensano. L'effetto reddito va da $x^A$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo, mentre l'effetto sostituzione va da $x^B$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo. 

In questo caso come vedi all'aumentare deiprezzi la quantità domandata non varia. Si sposta quindi il vincolo di bilancio dei
\nopar{prezzi iniziali finchè non è tangente alla curva di indifferenza finale. Si nota quindi che effetto reddito e sostituzione si compensano. L'effetto reddito va da $x^A$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo, mentre l'effetto sostituzione va da $x^B$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo.}
\switchcolumn
    \usebox\tempbox
\end{paracol}
\continuepar

In questo caso come vedi all'aumentare dei prezzi la quantità domandata non varia. Si sposta quindi il vincolo di bilancio dei prezzi iniziali finchè non è tangente alla curva di indifferenza finale. Si nota quindi che effetto reddito e sostituzione si compensano. L'effetto reddito va da $x^A$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo, mentre l'effetto sostituzione va da $x^B$ a $x^C$ ed è negativo. 

\subsubsection{Scomposizione di Hicks: bene inferiore e di Giffen con $p' > p$, \textit{SE < IE}}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Foto grafici/l-11:3.png}}% get width
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}%
\begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy
La quantità domandata a seguito di un aumento di prezzo è più grande di quella iniziale, come puoi vedere $x^{A}>x^{B}$. Questo accade perchè l'effetto reddito è molto forte, mentre l'effetto sostituzione è decisamente più debole e quindi il consumatore sceglierà di acquistare di più.
\switchcolumn
    \usebox\tempbox
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```