# wrapfig across sections

Tags: wrapfigure

I need to add a long image to the side of the document, but the text does not seem to be wrapping around the image.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}
\section{sec1}
\lipsum[1-4]

\subsection{subsec1}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
\label{wrap-fig:1}
% \includegraphics[height=15cm]{sample}
\rule{5cm}{15cm}
\caption{A wrapped figure going nicely inside the text.}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\lipsum[5]

\section{sec2}
\lipsum[5-12]

\end{document}
```

How can I wrap the image properly?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but `\label` has to be put either inside the argument of `\caption` or after `\caption` (the optimum is inside the argument).

Comment: You might consider using paracol instead of wrapfigure.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586554/collision-between-wrapping-environments/586676?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#586676 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\vspace` with a negative margin before `\end{wrapfigure}` fixes the problem, although this probably doesn't get to the root of it.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
  \label{wrap-fig:1}
    \rule{5cm}{15cm}
  \caption{A wrapped figure going nicely inside the text.}
  \vspace{-10cm}  % as an example, exact margin to be selected
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem does not seem to be the `wrapfigure` itself, but somehow `\lipsum` text does not behave and interact with it like regular text would.

If you use e.g `\blindtext` instead, you will get the expected wrapping:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}
    \section{sec1}
    \blindtext[4]   
    
    \subsection{subsec1}

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=15cm,width=5cm]{example-image}
        \caption{A wrapped figure going nicely inside the text.}
        \label{wrap-fig:1}
    \end{wrapfigure} 
    \blindtext
    
    
    \section{sec2}
    \blindtext[6]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Except, of course, that you will need to adjust the number of lines (optional) to handle the extra space.

Comment: Which is  behavior to be expected from wrapfigures. An explanation on how to deal with the number of lines can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31769/163512).

Comment: I am using `\lipsum` here in place of my actual text, which is having the same behaviour. Sounds like it is a problem with `\wrapfig` then?

Comment: In that case, I cannot reproduce your problem. For me using ``\blindtext`` or inserting actual text wraps as I've shown in my answer. I am guessing some other packages not included in your MWE are to blame. Have you tried inserting your specific text into the code from my answer?