# Position text boxes on the right or left of the main body text

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, wrapfigure, wrap, insbox

I frequently need to position a text box containing a small amount of text on either the right or left of the page, and wrap text around it. In this example I attempted to use wrapfig (though i have no image or figures).  Only  the first text box floats on the right.  Perhaps wrapfig is not the correct approach?

Sample code and ouptut below.
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white,colframe=black,sharp corners}  %framed box


\newcommand{\mytext}{ \lipsum[1] }

\newenvironment{icfloatbox}   %A box to float text around the left of.
{\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{2cm}\begin{mybox} another box in the icfloatbox.}
{\end{mybox} \end{wrapfigure}}



\begin{document}

%works
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{5cm}
\begin{mybox}
Expected on the right 1\end{mybox}
\end{wrapfigure}
\mytext%
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{5cm}
\begin{mybox}
Expected on the right 2\end{mybox}
\end{wrapfigure}
\mytext%
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{5cm}
\begin{mybox}
Expected on the right 3\end{mybox}
\end{wrapfigure}
\mytext% 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Uhm, your code works fine for me. (However, I've got an old system.)

Comment: @campa so all your boxes are positioned on the right the page?  that is what I am attempting in the example.

Comment: The results are the same with pdflatext or xelatex.  both at version 3.141592653

Comment: Yes, I get all boxes placed on the right with the text wrapping around them. But as I said I've got an older system, so newer updates might have broken something...

Comment: If I leave an empty line between `\mytext` and `\begin{wrapfigure}` second and third boxes are shown on the right. (I'm using pdflatex with a yesterday updated miktex system)

Comment: @ignasi that made no difference in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

I found [insbox](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/insbox) worked more reliably.  Hopefully with that and tcolorbox I can do everything i used to do in word (floating boxes with some info to the right or left).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white,colframe=black,sharp corners,width=3in}  %framed box

\newcommand{\dobox} {\begin{mybox}Box box box\end{mybox}}

\begin{document}

\dobox
ok
blah blah
\InsertBoxR{5}{\dobox}
\lipsum[1]
\InsertBoxR{2}{\dobox}
the end.
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is solution to wrap a paragraph around a box flushed to the right (or left) margin based on my previous answer.

No other packages were needed.

The command `\InsertBox` was defined, with 4 parameters.

`\InsertBox[<l or r (default} >]{<box content>}{<box width>}{<text to be shaped>}`

1. (optional) where to place the box in the text area: `r` or `l` (`r`,right,
   is the default);
2. content of the box;
3. desired box width;
4. paragraph to be shaped.

See [wrapping without extra packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622373/161015)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text 

%***************************************************************************************************
\newlength{\AboveSkipbox}
\setlength{\AboveSkipbox}{0.7\baselineskip}  % above space <<<<

\newlength{\Sidesepbox}
\setlength{\Sidesepbox}{1.5em} % side space <<<

\newlength{\BoxHeight}
\newlength{\ParHeight}  
\newlength{\FirstIndent}
\newlength{\FigureBoxWidth}
\newlength{\FigIndent}      
\newsavebox{\mybox} 
\newsavebox{\tmpbox}
%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127504/more-condensed-version-of-parshape
\makeatletter
\let\SavedIndent\parindent  
\let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
\@afterindenttrue
\def\newparshape{\parshape\@npshape0{}}
\def\@npshape#1#2#3{\ifx\\#3\expandafter\@@@npshape\else\expandafter\@@npshape\fi
    {#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\@@npshape#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \ifnum#3>\z@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\expandafter\@@npshape\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2 #4 #5}{\numexpr#3-1\relax}{#4}{#5}}%
    {\@npshape{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@@@npshape#1#2#3{#1 #2}
\def\SetFirstIndent{\if@afterindent\FirstIndent\SavedIndent\else\FirstIndent\z@\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\nlines}[1]{\the\numexpr#1/\baselineskip +1 \relax}     
\newcommand{\TypesetBox}[1]{\makebox[\linewidth][#1]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\ht\mybox-\AboveSkipbox\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox{\mybox}}}}     
\newcommand{\TypesetTextShortLong}[1]{%
    \hspace*{\parindent}
    \ifdim\dimexpr\ht\tmpbox+\dp\tmpbox<\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox+2\baselineskip\relax%short
    \hspace{-\parindent}\usebox{\tmpbox}\vspace{\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox+\AboveSkipbox-\ht\tmpbox-\dp\tmpbox\relax}
    \else%long
    #1\fi
}

\newcommand{\MakeFigureSpace}[1]{%
    \ifx#1l% left
    \setlength{\FigIndent}{\FigureBoxWidth}
    \else% right
    \setlength{\FigIndent}{0pt} 
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\InsertBox}[4][r]{%
    \SetFirstIndent%    
    \setlength{\FigureBoxWidth}{\dimexpr#3+\Sidesepbox\relax}   
    \sbox{\tmpbox}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\FigureBoxWidth\relax}{\hspace{\FirstIndent}#4}}
    \sbox{\mybox}{\fbox{\parbox{#3}{#2}}}%
    \MakeFigureSpace{#1}% Figure Indent = \parindent or Fig Box width
    \vspace{-\baselineskip} 
    \hspace{\dimexpr-\FigIndent-\parindent\relax}\TypesetBox{#1}    
    \newparshape% shape paragraph text
    {\nlines{\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox+\baselineskip\relax}}{\FigIndent}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\FigureBoxWidth\relax}%
    {1}{0pt}{\linewidth}\\
    \TypesetTextShortLong{#4} 
}
%***************************************************************************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \InsertBox{Expected on the right 1}{0.3\textwidth}{\kant[2]}
    
    \kant[9]
    
    \InsertBox[l]{\bfseries \large As I have shown elsewhere, Aristotle tells
        us that the objects in space and time, in the full sense of these
        terms, would be falsified.}{0.4\textwidth}{\kant[4]}

\end{document}
```