# How to avoid unnecessary linespacing in latex figures?

Tags: line-spacing, wrapfigure

I am formatting a research paper and adding biographies of authors, but there is unnecessary linespacing as it can be seen in the image below.

[image: Example]

I am using following latex formatting from a journal.

```
%% Biogrphy
\newcommand{\Biography}[2]{
\vspace*{4mm}%
\parskip=0mm%
\parindent=1em%
\baselineskip 15pt%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}%
\normalsize%

\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}{3.1cm}\vspace{-3.5mm}
\includegraphics{#1}
\end{wrapfigure}

\ \vspace{-.25cm}

\noindent\small #2}

\def\qed{\hfill$\Box$}

\renewcommand\figurename{\bfseries Fig.}
\renewcommand\tablename{\bfseries Table}
```

This is how I am using it in paper.

```
\Biography{fcs-2}{Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.}
\par
\Biography{fcs-2}{Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.}... and so on..
```

Comment: wrapfigure has an optional argument to specify the number of lines to cut in so you can cut in less at the column break. Also always leave a paragraph break at the end of a size command scope to get the correct line spacing so  `\small #2\par}`

Comment: it does not do anything. still same issue. I add \par before \Biography tag.

Comment: there is no reason to use `\par` before `\Bilbliography` a blank line would do the same, but you do need `\par` where I said, before the `}` that ends `\small`   If you use the optional argument to resumce the number of lines that are cut in, then it will not carry the cutin over to th etop of the next column. Currently you are forcing `[9]` 9 lines cut in even at the bottom where there are only 6 lines so you are explicitly forcing wrapfig to cut in the two lines at the top of the next column.

Comment: removed optional argument[9] from wrap figure \begin{wrapfigure}{1}{3.1cm}\vspace{-4mm} , updated \noindent\small #2 \par} and removed \par before \Bilbliography. Still same issue.

Comment: yes as I say you would need to expose that option as an option to your command and use `[5]`  in the case where it wraps over the column. If you provided an example that showed the problem someone could post a tested answer.

Comment: Using [5] affects the lines of other \Bilbliographies. I have provided it above what other information do you need?

Comment: There is a space for the text, why is it going on second column?

Comment: No I mean use `\Bibliography[5]{...}{...}` in that case and arrange that the optional argument is passed to wrapfig.  The code you have posted can not be run to see the problem. It is better to post a complete small document (yiu can use `example-image` as the image as it is available for tests

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using template from here https://journal.hep.com.cn/fcs/EN/column/column11258.shtml

Comment: One wonders how long this journal has been using this code.  I would add \newpage before each problematic \Biography.  See the needspace package.

Comment: Ir you are not **required** to use this \Biography, one could do a better job.  At the very least it should end the text with \wrapfill (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526518/wrapfigure-two-figures-left-and-right-with-text-in-between/526594?r=SearchResults&s=1|41.0437#526594)

Comment: @JohnKormylo adding new page does nothing.

Comment: The only way \newpage\Biography would not be different is if the text is shorter than the picture, in which case you definitely need \wrapfill.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your problem with the following MWE, and adding `\newpage` fixed it.  I did have to modify `\includegraphics` to handle the image.

Like I said, one could really do a better job of `\Biography`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{showframe}

%% Biogrphy
\newcommand{\Biography}[2]{
\vspace*{4mm}%
\parskip=0mm%
\parindent=1em%
\baselineskip 15pt%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}%
\normalsize%

\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}{3.1cm}\vspace{-3.5mm}
\includegraphics[width=3.1cm, height=7\baselineskip, keepaspectratio]{#1}% options required to fit space
\end{wrapfigure}

\ \vspace{-.25cm}

\noindent\small #2}

\def\qed{\hfill$\Box$}

\renewcommand\figurename{\bfseries Fig.}
\renewcommand\tablename{\bfseries Table}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{40\baselineskip}

%\newpage
\Biography{example-image}{Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.}
\par
\Biography{example-image}{Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.}... and so on..

\end{document}
```