# Trying to put a wrapfigure next to a wraptable

Tags: wrapfigure, wrapfig

everyone.

I'm having trouble with the position of a `wrapfigure` environment. And it's weird because I've managed to accomplish it in the previous page. I'll explain myself.

Here's the code (I've let out everything irrelevant to the problem):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\author{\textit{Samuel G. Guerrero Camarero}}

\title{\textbf{Práctica 10. Determinación de la banda prohibida del germanio.}}


\topmargin=-3cm
\oddsidemargin=-0.55cm
\textwidth=18cm
\textheight=25cm
\topmargin=-2cm

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{montaje.png}
\caption{Montaje del experimento.}
\label{fig:montaje}
\end{figure}

\section{Resultados y discusión}
\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{T (ºC)} & \textbf{V(V)} & \textbf{$\Delta$V(V)} \\ \hline
35              & 2.676         & 0.004          \\ \hline
49              & 1.553         & 0.004          \\ \hline
57              & 1.138         & 0.004          \\ \hline
59              & 1.084         & 0.004          \\ \hline
67              & 0.7909        & 0.0007         \\ \hline
73              & 0.6701        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
78              & 0.6701        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
83              & 0.4680        & 0.0005         \\ \hline
90              & 0.3749        & 0.0005         \\ \hline
100             & 0.2716        & 0.0004         \\ \hline
98              & 0.2891        & 0.0004         \\ \hline
94              & 0.3187        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
89              & 0.3808        & 0.0005         \\ \hline
83              & 0.4458        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
78              & 0.5539        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
73              & 0.6408        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
67              & 0.8076        & 0.0007         \\ \hline
63              & 0.9587        & 0.0008         \\ \hline
55              & 1.280         & 0.003          \\ \hline
51              & 1.468         & 0.004          \\ \hline
47              & 1.666         & 0.004          \\ \hline
44              & 1.974         & 0.004          \\ \hline
40              & 2.274         & 0.004          \\ \hline
36              & 2.654         & 0.004          \\ \hline
32              & 3.108         & 0.005          \\ \hline
29              & 3.577         & 0.005          \\ \hline
25              & 4.089         & 0.005          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Datos recogidos.}
\label{tab:TempvsV}
\end{wraptable}
Los datos obtenido son los de la tabla \ref{tab:TempvsV}. El error calculado es el que se indica en el manual del multímetro \cite{MANUALMULTIM}, que es 0.05\% del valor leído más 3 dígitos.
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{RvsT.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:RvsT}
\end{wrapfigure}
 Haciendo uso de la ley de Ohm, (\ref{eq:Ohm}), y sabiendo que la corriente se ha mantenido en todo momento en $(6 \pm 1)$ mA, podemos transformar el voltaje en resistencia. Y representándola en función de la temperatura (pasada a Kelvin), obtenemos la figura \ref{fig:RvsT}, cuyos valores pueden verse en la tabla \ref{tab:TvsR}.\\
 



Usando los valores dados para las constantes de las ecuaciones (\ref{eq:movilidades1}) y (\ref{eq:movilidades2}), podemos sacar el valor del cociente que aparece en la ecuación (\ref{eq:LN1R}),  $C_h/C_e=21.87555$. Con esto, y viendo que la temperatura en nuestro experimento se mantiene dentro del intervalo [290,380] K, la variación en este intervalo del 
\clearpage

segundo término del miembro de la derecha de la ecuación (\ref{eq:LN1R}), es decir, del término
\begin{equation}
ln\left(T^{-0.16}+\frac{C_h}{C_e}T^{-0.83}\right),
\label{eq:termLN}
\end{equation}
es 
\begin{equation}
ln\left(380^{-0.16}+\frac{C_h}{C_e}380^{-0.83}\right)-ln\left(290^{-0.16}+\frac{C_h}{C_e}290^{-0.83}\right) \simeq -0.099255
\label{eq:varLN}
\end{equation}

\begin{wraptable}{l}{0.25\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{T (K)} & \textbf{R($\Omega$)} & \textbf{$\Delta$R($\Omega$)} \\ \hline
306            & 446.0           & 0.9              \\ \hline
320            & 258.8           & 0.7              \\ \hline
328            & 189.7           & 0.6              \\ \hline
330            & 180.7           & 0.6              \\ \hline
338            & 131.8           & 0.2              \\ \hline
344            & 111.7           & 0.2              \\ \hline
349            & 111.7           & 0.2              \\ \hline
354            & 78.00           & 0.12             \\ \hline
361            & 62.48           & 0.10             \\ \hline
371            & 45.27           & 0.09             \\ \hline
369            & 48.18           & 0.09             \\ \hline
365            & 53.12           & 0.09             \\ \hline
360            & 63.46           & 0.10             \\ \hline
354            & 74.30           & 0.11             \\ \hline
349            & 92.32           & 0.13             \\ \hline
344            & 106.80          & 0.15             \\ \hline
338            & 134.60          & 0.18             \\ \hline
334            & 159.7           & 0.2              \\ \hline
326            & 213.3           & 0.6              \\ \hline
322            & 244.7           & 0.7              \\ \hline
318            & 277.7           & 0.7              \\ \hline
315            & 329.0           & 0.7              \\ \hline
311            & 379.0           & 0.8              \\ \hline
307            & 442.0           & 0.8              \\ \hline
303            & 518.0           & 0.9              \\ \hline
300            & 596.17          & 0.99             \\ \hline
296            & 681.5           & 1.1              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{tab:TvsR}
\end{wraptable}

En cambio, si comparamos la variación de $ln\left(\frac1R\right)$ para los dos valores de $R$ extremos recogidos en la tabla \ref{tab:TvsR}, estos son, (681.5 $\pm$ 1.1) y (45.27 $\pm$ 0.09) $\Omega$ (para 296 y 371 K, respectivamente), tenemos que 
\begin{equation}
ln\left(\frac1{45.27}\right)-ln\left(\frac1{681.5}\right) \simeq 2.712.
\end{equation}
Que es una variación de dos órdenes de magnitud menor que (\ref{eq:varLN}). Por tanto podemos despreciar su contribución y considerar el término (\ref{eq:termLN}) constante dentro del intervalo de temperatura en el que estamos. Dicho esto, la ecuación (\ref{eq:LN1R}) será del tipo
\begin{equation}
ln\left(\frac1{R}\right)= B - \frac{E_g(0)}{2k_BT}.
\end{equation}
Y por tanto, si representáramos $ln(1/R)$ en función de $1/T$ deberíamos obtener una dependencia prácticamente lineal.\\

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{ln1RconAJUSTE.png}
\caption{}
\end{wrapfigure}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

My problem is that I want the second `wraptable` and `wrapfigure` to be on the same page, but the `wrapfigure` doesn't seem to respond to the position parameter (the 'r' or 'l') and it keeps showing like this:

[image: Wrapfig over table]

covering half of the table.
In the previous page you can see that I have something similar showing

[image: Previous page]

I want the problematic one like this but inversed (the table o the left and the image on the right) and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't start another wrapfigure OR wrapteable until the first is done, at least not and get them to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other (less fragile but more difficult) way to do this is to use minipages and saveboxes.  In this case, the breaks came between paragraphs.  If you need to break a paragraph at the end of a minipage, you can use `\parfillskip=0pt`.  Note that determining the optional argument for wrapfigure is also largely trial and error.

Note that tabular places the first baseline at the `\hline`, not the text.
Also, minipages set `\parindent=0pt`.

Using a `center` environment for figures serves four functions.  You can't use a `figure` environment inside a minipage (not in outer par mode).  It isolates the `\captionof` from the rest of the minipage.  It provides a space above and below; not quite the right space (`\intextsep`), but close enough.  And of course, it centers the figure.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\author{\textit{Samuel G. Guerrero Camarero}}

\title{\textbf{Práctica 10. Determinación de la banda prohibida del germanio.}}


\topmargin=-3cm
\oddsidemargin=-0.55cm
\textwidth=18cm
\textheight=25cm
\topmargin=-2cm

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]% friends don't let friends use [H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{Montaje del experimento.}
\label{fig:montaje}
\end{figure}

\section{Resultados y discusión}
\savebox{\tempbox}{% measure width, do NOT include caption
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{T (ºC)} & \textbf{V(V)} & \textbf{$\Delta$V(V)} \\ \hline
35              & 2.676         & 0.004          \\ \hline
49              & 1.553         & 0.004          \\ \hline
57              & 1.138         & 0.004          \\ \hline
59              & 1.084         & 0.004          \\ \hline
67              & 0.7909        & 0.0007         \\ \hline
73              & 0.6701        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
78              & 0.6701        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
83              & 0.4680        & 0.0005         \\ \hline
90              & 0.3749        & 0.0005         \\ \hline
100             & 0.2716        & 0.0004         \\ \hline
98              & 0.2891        & 0.0004         \\ \hline
94              & 0.3187        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
89              & 0.3808        & 0.0005         \\ \hline
83              & 0.4458        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
78              & 0.5539        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
73              & 0.6408        & 0.0006         \\ \hline
67              & 0.8076        & 0.0007         \\ \hline
63              & 0.9587        & 0.0008         \\ \hline
55              & 1.280         & 0.003          \\ \hline
51              & 1.468         & 0.004          \\ \hline
47              & 1.666         & 0.004          \\ \hline
44              & 1.974         & 0.004          \\ \hline
40              & 2.274         & 0.004          \\ \hline
36              & 2.654         & 0.004          \\ \hline
32              & 3.108         & 0.005          \\ \hline
29              & 3.577         & 0.005          \\ \hline
25              & 4.089         & 0.005          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}% end of savebox

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

Los datos obtenido son los de la tabla \ref{tab:TempvsV}. El error calculado es el que se indica en el manual del multímetro \cite{MANUALMULTIM}, que es 0.05\% del valor leído más 3 dígitos.


\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{example-image-b}
\captionof{figure}{}
\label{fig:RvsT}
\end{center}

 Haciendo uso de la ley de Ohm, (\ref{eq:Ohm}), y sabiendo que la corriente se ha mantenido en todo momento en $(6 \pm 1)$ mA, podemos transformar el voltaje en resistencia. Y representándola en función de la temperatura (pasada a Kelvin), obtenemos la figura \ref{fig:RvsT}, cuyos valores pueden verse en la tabla \ref{tab:TvsR}.

Usando los valores dados para las constantes de las ecuaciones (\ref{eq:movilidades1}) y (\ref{eq:movilidades2}), podemos sacar el valor del cociente que aparece en la ecuación (\ref{eq:LN1R}),  $C_h/C_e=21.87555$. Con esto, y viendo que la temperatura en nuestro experimento se mantiene dentro del intervalo [290,380] K, la variación en este intervalo del 
segundo término del miembro de la derecha de la ecuación (\ref{eq:LN1R}), es decir, del término
\begin{equation}
ln\left(T^{-0.16}+\frac{C_h}{C_e}T^{-0.83}\right),
\label{eq:termLN}
\end{equation}
es 
\begin{equation}
ln\left(380^{-0.16}+\frac{C_h}{C_e}380^{-0.83}\right)-ln\left(290^{-0.16}+\frac{C_h}{C_e}290^{-0.83}\right) \simeq -0.099255
\label{eq:varLN}
\end{equation}
\hrule height0pt % prevent minipage from absorbing space below equation
\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\tempbox}
% wrapfig usually adds \vskip\intextsep at the top and bottom
\usebox\tempbox
\captionof{table}{Datos recogidos.}
\label{tab:TempvsV}
\end{minipage}

\savebox{\tempbox}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{T (K)} & \textbf{R($\Omega$)} & \textbf{$\Delta$R($\Omega$)} \\ \hline
306            & 446.0           & 0.9              \\ \hline
320            & 258.8           & 0.7              \\ \hline
328            & 189.7           & 0.6              \\ \hline
330            & 180.7           & 0.6              \\ \hline
338            & 131.8           & 0.2              \\ \hline
344            & 111.7           & 0.2              \\ \hline
349            & 111.7           & 0.2              \\ \hline
354            & 78.00           & 0.12             \\ \hline
361            & 62.48           & 0.10             \\ \hline
371            & 45.27           & 0.09             \\ \hline
369            & 48.18           & 0.09             \\ \hline
365            & 53.12           & 0.09             \\ \hline
360            & 63.46           & 0.10             \\ \hline
354            & 74.30           & 0.11             \\ \hline
349            & 92.32           & 0.13             \\ \hline
344            & 106.80          & 0.15             \\ \hline
338            & 134.60          & 0.18             \\ \hline
334            & 159.7           & 0.2              \\ \hline
326            & 213.3           & 0.6              \\ \hline
322            & 244.7           & 0.7              \\ \hline
318            & 277.7           & 0.7              \\ \hline
315            & 329.0           & 0.7              \\ \hline
311            & 379.0           & 0.8              \\ \hline
307            & 442.0           & 0.8              \\ \hline
303            & 518.0           & 0.9              \\ \hline
300            & 596.17          & 0.99             \\ \hline
296            & 681.5           & 1.1              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\strut}% end of savebox

En cambio, si comparamos la variación de $ln\left(\frac1R\right)$ para los dos valores de $R$ extremos recogidos en la tabla \ref{tab:TvsR}, estos son, (681.5 $\pm$ 1.1) y (45.27 $\pm$ 0.09) $\Omega$ (para 296 y 371 K, respectivamente), tenemos que 
\begin{equation}
ln\left(\frac1{45.27}\right)-ln\left(\frac1{681.5}\right) \simeq 2.712.
\end{equation}
Que es una variación de dos órdenes de magnitud menor que (\ref{eq:varLN}). Por tanto podemos despreciar su contribución y considerar el término (\ref{eq:termLN}) constante dentro del intervalo de temperatura en el que estamos. Dicho esto, la ecuación (\ref{eq:LN1R}) será del tipo
\begin{equation}
ln\left(\frac1{R}\right)= B - \frac{E_g(0)}{2k_BT}.
\end{equation}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\tempbox}
\usebox\tempbox
\captionof{table}{}
\label{tab:TvsR}
\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}% overkill

\noindent
Y por tanto, si representáramos $ln(1/R)$ en función de $1/T$ deberíamos obtener una dependencia prácticamente lineal.

\noindent\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{example-image-c}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. It works beautifully. Now it's my turn to understand how it all works hahaha Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also use paracol instead of minipages.  It is basically the same process, except that you CAN put figures inside paracol and it doesn't change \parindent.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509450/two-wrapfigure-overlapping-delay-starting-point-of-wrapfigure-associated-text/509522?r=SearchResults&s=8|26.0477#509522 for example.