# Blank vertical space in minipage. Why?

Tags: boxes, minipage

everyone.

A few weeks ago I posted a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569631/trying-to-put-a-wrapfigure-next-to-a-wraptable/569654?noredirect=1#comment1436211_569654) about a similar topic. I'm in the process of learning to use boxes and minipages. It was going well untill yesterday. I was trying to do practically the same thing as in the question mentioned above; I'm trying to put a table next to a minipage with some text and a figure on it, but I can't seem to align the top line of both minipages. I leave you a image about the issue:

[image]

It's the blank space above equation (3.1). Why does this happen? I've been playing with the adjustment parameter (the t, b or c), but doesn't quite solve it.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\author{\textit{Samuel G. Guerrero Camarero}}

\title{\textbf{Práctica 12. Conductividad eléctrica y térmica de metales.}}


\oddsidemargin=-0.55cm
\textwidth=18cm
\textheight=25cm
\topmargin=-2cm

\begin{document}

\noindent Ahora, si recordamos la ley de Ohm, $V=RI$, la pendiente que hemos obtenido es la resistencia del circuito, $R= 10.6273 \pm 0.1385$ $\mu\Omega$. Y esta se puede relacionar con la conductividad por\\

 
\savebox{\tempbox}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Corriente (A)} & \textbf{Tensión ($\mu$V)} \\ \hline
0.25 $\pm$ 0.02        & 13.0 $\pm$ 0.4              \\ \hline
0.28 $\pm$ 0.02        & 13.5 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
0.31 $\pm$ 0.02        & 14.1 $\pm$ 0.4             \\ \hline
0.37 $\pm$ 0.02        & 14.9 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
0.43 $\pm$ 0.02        & 15.3 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
0.58 $\pm$ 0.03        & 16.4 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
0.69 $\pm$ 0.3         & 17.4 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
0.79 $\pm$ 0.3         & 18.7 $\pm$ 0.4                  \\ \hline
0.83 $\pm$ 0.3         & 19.3 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
0.91 $\pm$ 0.04        & 20.3 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
0.95 $\pm$ 0.04        & 20.5 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
1.10 $\pm$ 0.04         & 21.5 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
1.22 $\pm$ 0.05        & 22.7 $\pm$ 0.4           \\ \hline
1.3 $\pm$ 0.05         & 23.5 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
1.45 $\pm$ 0.05        & 25.2 $\pm$ 0.5            \\ \hline
1.65 $\pm$ 0.06        & 27.6 $\pm$ 0.4            \\ \hline
1.74 $\pm$ 0.06        & 28.0 $\pm$ 0.5            \\ \hline
2.04 $\pm$ 0.07        & 31.6 $\pm$ 0.5            \\ \hline
4.92 $\pm$ 0.15        & 64.0 $\pm$ 0.6            \\ \hline
5.80 $\pm$ 0.18        & 73.5 $\pm$ 0.7            \\ \hline
6.7 $\pm$ 0.2          & 84.2 $\pm$ 0.7            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}} %end of TEMPBOX

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\tempbox}
    \usebox\tempbox
    \captionof{table}{Datos recogidos.}
    \label{tab:IvsV}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}

%   \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}% overkill
\begin{equation}
    R=\frac1{\sigma} \frac{L}{S}.
    \label{eq:Rsigma}
\end{equation}

\noindent Donde $L$ es la longitud de la barra, (31.5 $\pm$ 0.1) cm, y $S$ su sección, 4.91$\cdot$10$^{-4}$ m$^{2}$. 

%%\setlength{\parindent}{10pt} 
%\vspace{\intextsep}
%\noindent %This is the minipage for the image
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% not really needed, but a good idea anyway
    \vskip\intextsep
    \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{IvsV}
\captionof{figure}{}
\label{fig:RvsT}
\end{minipage}%\vspace{\intextsep}

Por tanto, podemos despejar $\sigma$ de \ref{eq:Rsigma} y sustituir valores. Así, obtenemos la conductividad de nuestro material
\end{minipage}
\begin{equation}
    \sigma = (60367907 \pm 802624) \text{ S/m} \approx (60.4 \pm 0.8)\cdot 10^{6} \text{ S/m }
\end{equation}\\
El error de este y de demás cálculos se obtendrán de la herramienta online de cálculo de propagación de errores \cite{ERRpropag}. Si comparamos este valor con el tabulado \cite{cobreWIKI}, 58,108$\cdot$10$^{6}$ S/m, vemos que el valor es bastante cercano, difiriendo sólo un 3.8\%.\\

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not know why you use a savebox here but you want `\savebox{\tempbox}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}`  where the `[t]` on the tabular matches the one you have on minipage to top align. (The `%` is needed to avoid adding a space)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the missing `[t]`  optional argument of the `tabular` in the `\savebox` command, I also adapted the look of the `tabular` to the `booktabs` package that you already load. Additionally, I introduced the `siunitx` package to improve the alignment of the numbers in the table, I also used this package to typeset the varisous other numbers and their units. The output can easily be altered using the appropriate options in the  `\sisetup` command. Lastly, I also removed unrelated packages from the preamble. Please also keep in mind the correct load order of the `hyperref` package, which shoul (with a few exceptions) be the last package in your preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true, output-decimal-marker = {,}, per-mode=symbol, exponent-product=\cdot}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\author{\textit{Samuel G. Guerrero Camarero}}

\title{\textbf{Práctica 12. Conductividad eléctrica y térmica de metales.}}


\oddsidemargin=-0.55cm
\textwidth=18cm
\textheight=25cm
\topmargin=-2cm

\begin{document}

Ahora, si recordamos la ley de Ohm, $V=RI$, la pendiente que hemos obtenido es la resistencia del circuito, $R= \SI{10.6273(1385)}{\micro\ohm}$. Y esta se puede relacionar con la conductividad por\\

 
\savebox{\tempbox}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{S[table-format=1.2(3)]S[table-format=2.1(3)]}
\toprule
{\textbf{Corriente (\si{\ampere})}} & {\textbf{Tensión (\si{\micro\volt})}} \\ 
\midrule
0.25(2)    & 13.0(40)  \\ 
0.28(2)    & 13.5(40)  \\ 
0.31(2)    & 14.1(40)  \\
\addlinespace
0.37(2)    & 14.9(40)  \\ 
0.43(2)    & 15.3(40)  \\ 
0.58(3)    & 16.4(40)  \\
\addlinespace 
0.69(30)   & 17.4(40)  \\ 
0.79(30)   & 18.7(40)  \\
0.83(30)   & 19.3(40)  \\ 
\addlinespace
0.91(4)    & 20.3(40)  \\ 
0.95(4)    & 20.5(40)  \\ 
1.10(4)    & 21.5(40)  \\
\addlinespace
1.22(5)    & 22.7(40)  \\ 
1.3(5)     & 23.5(40)  \\ 
1.45(5)    & 25.2(50)  \\
\addlinespace 
1.65(6)    & 27.6(40)  \\ 
1.74(6)    & 28.0(50)  \\ 
2.04(7)    & 31.6(50)  \\ 
\addlinespace
4.92(15)   & 64.0(60)  \\ 
5.80(18)   & 73.5(70)  \\ 
6.7(20)    & 84.2(70)  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}} %end of TEMPBOX

\begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\tempbox}
    \usebox\tempbox
    \captionof{table}{Datos recogidos.}
    \label{tab:IvsV}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}
\begin{equation}
    R=\frac1{\sigma} \frac{L}{S}.
    \label{eq:Rsigma}
\end{equation}
Donde $L$ es la longitud de la barra, \SI{31.5(1)}{\cm}, y $S$ su sección, \SI{4.91e-4}{\meter\squared}. 


\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% not really needed, but a good idea anyway
    \vskip\intextsep
    \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{}
\label{fig:RvsT}
\end{minipage}%\vspace{\intextsep}

Por tanto, podemos despejar $\sigma$ de \ref{eq:Rsigma} y sustituir valores. Así, obtenemos la conductividad de nuestro material
\end{minipage}
\begin{equation}
    \sigma = \SI{60367907(802624)}{S\per\meter} \approx \SI{60.4(8)e6}{S\per\meter}
\end{equation}
El error de este y de demás cálculos se obtendrán de la herramienta online de cálculo de propagación de errores \cite{ERRpropag}. Si comparamos este valor con el tabulado \cite{cobreWIKI}, \SI{58,108e6}{S\per\meter}, vemos que el valor es bastante cercano, difiriendo sólo un 3.8\%.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, I love the look of it, really. And i know my preamble is a disaster. What I do is copy and paste the same one every time I star a new document. And so I have a lot of packages that I don't really use. I know it's very pro, but it works for me hahaha

Comment: @SamuelGuerrero: While a messy preamble might currently "work"  it is usually better to stucture it, follow specific load orders (where important)  and most importantly, only include packages you actually use.

Comment: Yeah. I kind of know that. I'll try to work on them. Thanks a lot!