# Wrap figure wraps wrong

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

my problem is, that the wrapping occurs a bit strange. Maybe someone can help with this problem.
The code is:

```
   \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
  \captionsetup{width=.2\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Figures/Eulerpolcomp.jpg}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Eulerpol whole earth}
  \label{fig:EPE}
\end{wrapfigure}
If the orange lines are now assumed to be the orientation of the plate, an intersection can be found with a line perpendicular to the orange line. This is shown in \autoref{fig:EPE}viewed from the whole earth. Thereby the lines result in a great circle when they are drawn around the planet. \\

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
  \captionsetup{width=.2\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Figures/Eulerpole2.jpg}
  \end{center}
  \caption{close up}
  \label{fig:EP2}
\end{wrapfigure}
Several intersections can be found. Since in this case about 10 lines are drawn, the two clusters can be chosen (\autoref{fig:EP2}). Further processing has shown that the yellow Euler pole is not optimal and a little wrong rotation occurs. If the second cyan coloured pole is taken, the result becomes more credible. The assumed Euler pole lies at 57°46'N and 38°17'W. However, these data cannot be converted with Matlab, so they are still calculated in decimal degrees. The result is a latitude of 57.8N and a longitude of 38.3W.
```

And it shows something like that:

[image]

I tried it with {R} and with {r}

thanks for help

Comment: your code cannot be tested. But try to replace the center environment by the `\centering` command.

Comment: Hi Janine, welcome! Can you please change your snippet to a complete example, compilable by us? Probably you should just state the size of the inset (with the optional `[lines]` parameter), but I can't check. You can use `example-image` for your images, it's in all LaTeX distributions. (Also, what @UlrikeFischer said).

Comment: You can't start L until after the R is done.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569631/trying-to-put-a-wrapfigure-next-to-a-wraptable and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526518/wrapfigure-two-figures-left-and-right-with-text-in-between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it using paracol.  Note that neither paragraph is long enough to wrap around the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\globalcounter{figure}

\begin{document}

\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-0.2\textwidth}% left column
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[h]% use \intextsep (except at top of page}
  %\centering would be redundant
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
  \caption{Eulerpol whole earth}
  \label{fig:EPE}
\end{figure}
\switchcolumn
If the orange lines are now assumed to be the orientation of the plate, an intersection can be found with a line perpendicular to the orange line. This is shown in \autoref{fig:EPE} viewed from the whole earth. Thereby the lines result in a great circle when they are drawn around the planet. \strut
\end{paracol}

\setcolumnwidth{0.2\textwidth}% left column
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{figure}[h]% use \intextsep
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
  \caption{close up}
  \label{fig:EP2}
\end{figure}
\switchcolumn
Several intersections can be found. Since in this case about 10 lines are drawn, the two clusters can be chosen (\autoref{fig:EP2}). Further processing has shown that the yellow Euler pole is not optimal and a little wrong rotation occurs. If the second cyan coloured pole is taken, the result becomes more credible. The assumed Euler pole lies at 57°46'N and 38°17'W. However, these data cannot be converted with Matlab, so they are still calculated in decimal degrees. The result is a latitude of 57.8N and a longitude of 38.3W.
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. But now there is the small problem, that the pictures starting only on the second line.  Means the picture is slightly hanging lower than the section of the text starts. Is there any possibility to change?

Comment: If you remove the [h] from `\begin{figure}` it will place the figure at the top of the column, slightly above the start of text.  I was trying to reproduce wrapfig's behavior.