# trying to align wrap figure with [t]

Tags: align, wrapfigure, layout

So I'm trying my best to align my subsections this way:

```
\subsubsection{Cylindrical Robot Arm:}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{II.Theoretical Concept and state of the art/Industrial Robot Arms/Images/cylindrical Robot arm.png} 
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=0.1cm}
\caption{Cylindrical Robot Arm}
\end{wrapfigure}

This type of robot arms has at least one base rotary joint and one prismatic joint, which provide it with linear and rotational movement. These joints form a cylindrical coordinate system, making this robot arm effective and useful in industries that deal with tubing and cylindrical components as well as industries involving die casting...
\WFclear
\vspace{1cm}
```

The next subsection would be exactly the same except the wrapfigure will have an {l} argument instead.

This is what I get:

[image]

As you can see the alignment isn't right. I made sure the image doesn't have any free space. The image isn't aligned to the top of the subsubsection, which creates this weird look. There are 6 subsubsections and that made the page look bad.

Is there a way to fix this ? [t] didn't work on wrap figure and I'm not good with tables so I don't know how to make it look better.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621226/wrap-figure-wraps-wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\setlength\intextsep{0pt}` to eliminate extra top and below  space of the wrapped figure.

`\intextsep` is the vertical space placed above and below all floats not just a wrap figure. To affect  only  them  this code is added to the preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
```

From [Only the wrap figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436852/161015)

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy tex

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436852/161015
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}% eliminate extra top and below  space <<<<

\begin{document}
            
\subsubsection*{Cylindrical Robot Arm:}
    
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} 
    \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=0.1cm}
    \caption{Cylindrical Robot Arm}
\end{wrapfigure}

This type of robot arms has at least one base rotary joint and one prismatic joint, which provide it with linear and rotational movement. These joints form a cylindrical coordinate system, making this robot arm effective and useful in industries that deal with tubing and cylindrical components as well as industries involving die casting...

\subsubsection*{Delta Robot Arm:}   

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b} 
    \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=0.1cm}
    \caption{Delta Robot Arm}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\kant[1]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a nice explanation ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll include it in my document