multicols vs minipage for side-by-side purposes
I know that the multicol package is intended for a columnlayout and thus differs in its main purpose from minipage, but they can both be used for aligning lists, code, figures, etc. side-by-side if needed, as illustrated below:

My question is thus which environment is better for this purpose, and why? Do they both have their pros and cons for this purpose?
So far, I've noticed that the multicols environment is easier to set up as it automatically calculates the borders, but it seems more difficult to modify, particularly if you want to have \setlength{\columnsep}{1cm} one place and \setlength{\columnsep}{2cm} in another, for example, since it seems to be defined globally.
Meanwhile the minipage seems to be easier to modify once it's setup as the distance can be tweaked locally by the \hspace{<width>} command, for example. Do correct me if I'm wrong on these observations as well:)
Here's the code from my example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.5cm, hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{minted, multicol, parskip}

\begin{document}
Here are 2 snippets of code placed side-by-side with the usage of 2 distinct methods to make them appear side-by side. First off, we have the multicols solution:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=0.7cm, linenos, bgcolor=gray!20]{c}
// Fraction of read_uint_le()
...
    *out =
        ((uint32_t)b0)
        | ((uint32_t)b1 << 8)
        | ((uint32_t)b2 << 16)
        | ((uint32_t)b3 << 24);
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\columnbreak
\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=0.7cm, linenos, bgcolor=gray!20]{c}
// Fraction of read_uint_be()
...
    *out =
        ((uint32_t)b0 << 24)
        | ((uint32_t)b1 << 16)
        | ((uint32_t)b2 << 8)
        | ((uint32_t)b3);
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{multicols}

And here's the solution manipulating the boxes provided by the minipage command to make them appear side-by-side:
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=0.7cm, linenos, bgcolor=gray!20]{c}
// Fraction of read_uint_le()
...
    *out =
        ((uint32_t)b0)
        | ((uint32_t)b1 << 8)
        | ((uint32_t)b2 << 16)
        | ((uint32_t)b3 << 24);
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{10pt}%
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=0.7cm, linenos, bgcolor=gray!20]{c}
// Fraction of read_uint_be()
...
    *out =
        ((uint32_t)b0 << 24)
        | ((uint32_t)b1 << 16)
        | ((uint32_t)b2 << 8)
        | ((uint32_t)b3);
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


You asked, "My question is thus which environment is better for this purpose, and why? Do they both have their pros and cons for this purpose?" You've provided an example for which both approaches appear to work equally well, so the answer to the first question has to be "they can work equally well."

If you want to control the breaking point yourself, minipages are usually easier. If you want an automatic break, use multicols.

@Mico fair point. The example I used for showcasing side-by-side comparisons is quite an easy one. It was intended as a conversation starter, however, as I couldn't imagine a tricky scenario from the top of my head where it could be proven that one approach is definitively better than the other for this kind of usage. I do still think that we could perhaps draw some interesting conclusions from this simple example, however, because I haven't been able to find a direct comparison of the 2 environments on here in this regard

There is also paracol.  It allows uneven widths and supports floats.

@JohnKormylo I haven't heard of this package before, but minipage can also handle uneven widths by setting the first to \begin{minipage}{0.59\textwidth} and the 2nd one to \begin{minipage}{0.39\textwidth}, for example. The support for floats does seem interesting, however. I suppose the paracol package could perhaps be better for handling figures and tables or any other environment involved with floats?

For examples see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621226/wrap-figure-wraps-wrong/621233?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C44.4260#621233 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620345/indentation-problem-with-wrapfigure-and-listings/620404?r=SearchResults&s=10%7C37.0596#620404

An interesting alternative I'll keep in mind. It seems to be particularly useful when it comes to handling floats, like you initially suggested - Good one!

Use minipages if you want the code to be side-by-side. With multicol you do not get the result you want as can be seen with a simple change:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.5cm, hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{minted, multicol, parskip}

\begin{document}
blkllb

\vspace{0.8\textheight}

Here are 2 snippets of code placed side-by-side with the usage of 2 distinct methods to make them appear side-by side. First off, we have the multicols solution:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=0.7cm, linenos, bgcolor=gray!20]{c}
// Fraction of read_uint_le()
...
    *out =
        ((uint32_t)b0)
        | ((uint32_t)b1 << 8)
        | ((uint32_t)b2 << 16)
        | ((uint32_t)b3 << 24);
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\columnbreak
\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=0.7cm, linenos, bgcolor=gray!20]{c}
// Fraction of read_uint_be()
...
    *out =
        ((uint32_t)b0 << 24)
        | ((uint32_t)b1 << 16)
        | ((uint32_t)b2 << 8)
        | ((uint32_t)b3);
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}



Oooh, so the multicols environment would run into some trouble handling pagebreaks if intended to be used for side-by-side purposes? Also, are you running your example on a variation of LaTeX? When I load it on OverLeaf, it still doesn't display properly, but the wrong layout looks a bit different to yours

I use an up-to-date texlive 2024.
