# Is it okay to use \center and \justify without \endcenter and \endjustify?

Tags: environments

I would argue no.  I know that `\endcenter` and `\endjustify` are not trivial (both call `\endtrivlist`).  While they do not generate error messages, that does not mean they don't produce errors, just that the errors may be subtle and hard to trace.  If I see code which uses them that behaves oddly, my first response is to comment them all out and see if that fixes the problem.

However, I don't recall finding an actual case of errors caused by improperly nested center and justify environments.  It is possible that they were designed to be used that way as well as with `\begin{center}` etc?

Comment: Just to be sure: by "actual case of errors" you really mean (La)TeX error, and not only garbage output, right?

Comment: @campa - No, I mean a problem which can be fixed simply by properly nesting the environments.  Something subtle.

Comment: No `\center` should never be used as a command, use `\centering` similarly `\justifying` (ragged2e package) but you should almost ever need to specify `justify` as it is the default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The declaration form for centering is `\centering` (`\center` should never be used: it is just the internal implementation of the `center` environment, certainly never use without the matching `\end`)

Similarly, the ragged2e package which provides a `justify` environment provides a declaration form `\justifying` (although there are few circumstances where either should be used.)